# Disabling checkbox in layers list while exporting in qgis2web

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis-plugins, qgis2web

Is there a possibility to disable the checkbox on certain layers in the layers list (Leaflet export)?

I found something similar already here:
[qgis2web - show specific layers in layer list](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333098/qgis2web-show-specific-layers-in-layer-list)

but unfortunately, when I export the WebMap, I don't have a 'layers.js' I could work with to change the code.

Comment: Try to find a file other than layers.js. There is rather no option when the map has been generated leaving behind all the settings somewhere. It definitely should come out somewhere.